# What is an "addedToBoard" notification in Trello API?

Tags: api, trello

[Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#get-1-members-member-id-or-username-notifications-filter) indicates there is a type of notification called "addedToBoard". Does any one knows how to trigger this notification?

I tried adding a member to an existing private and public board but it always triggers an "invitedToBoard" notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly add someone to a board (without the invitation process) when the board belongs to an organization he is a member of, and that triggers this action type.